# numerology .. how to shorten code..?

Tags: python

I have written this code for finding the numerological value of a name. Is there any way in which i can shorten the code, or nest one loop inside the other?

```
alphabets = {"A":1,"I":1,"J":1, "Q":1,"Y":1,"B":2,"K":2,"R":3,"C":3,"G":3,"L":3,"S":3,"D":4,"M":4,"T":4,"H":5,"E":5,"N":5,"X":5,"U":6,"V":6,"W":6,"O":7, "Z":7,"P":8,"F":8}

word =input("your numerology score is :") #since i am using python 3 to code this

def digit_sum(n):
    #prepare a list of numbers in n convert to string and reconvert
    numbers=[]
    for digit in str(n):
        numbers.append(int(digit))
    # add up the total of numbers    
    total=0
    for number in numbers:
        total += number
    return total  

def numerology(word):
        total = 0
        for letter in word.upper():
            total += alphabets[letter]
            total = digit_sum(total)

        return total

print (numerology(word))
```

To understand what is meant by numerological value, please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerology#Latin_alphabet_systems.

Comment: Maybe it's more appropriate over there : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?tab=active

Answer (score 3):

```
alphabets = {"A":1,"I":1,"J":1, "Q":1,"Y":1,"B":2,"K":2,"R":3,"C":3,"G":3,"L":3,"S":3,"D":4,"M":4,"T":4,"H":5,"E":5,"N":5,"X":5,"U":6,"V":6,"W":6,"O":7, "Z":7,"P":8,"F":8}

name = "this is a sample name"

digits = str(sum([alphabets[l] for l in name.upper() if l in alphabets.keys()]))

numerological_value = int(digits) % 9

if numerological_value == 0:
    numerological_value = 9

print(numerological_value)
```

Comment: I'm trying to work out if this matches the posted code, which calls `digit_sum` over and over in a loop. But it does look more like the idea for the problem.

Comment: o God it is 1 line code..!! it took me hours to write this..with research..!!

Comment: also my code only takes up one word  eg: the first name  how do i  make it take two or more words eg: first name , middle and the last name

Comment: hang on a second

Comment: the above one liner code gives 2 digits instead of the final one. digit , eg: nikhl returns 16 instead of 7.. ( it should finally add 1+6)

Comment: I've updated my answer to have it work with name composed by more than one word.

Comment: Do you mean that letters with the same digit has to be counted just once?

Comment: @niksy You did not explain this fully in your question. Please edit your question to include all of your requirements. Maybe you need to explain what "numerological means", for example.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't get it until now

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms i have created a code to calculate the numerological value of a name....1. i wanted to know if i can shorten the code. 2. my code returns value only for one name, eg the first name.and throws up error on the last name or middle name...is added... Numerological value , is the numerlogical value of the name.. eg : numerology , a number is assigned to each alphabet and when you type in the name it returns a number a single digit number..

Comment: @niksy I've updated my answer, now it should be correct. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Excuse me, I don't get it. Could you explain me a little better?

Comment: Yes, you are right. And I think the cause is the `total = digit_sum(total)` into the for loop. Although my implementation seems to be correct in order to achieve the numerology value. If I'm wrong, please @niksy correct me.

Comment: @IlarioPierbattista Feel free to revert the edit if you don't like it. I tried putting that info in a comment, but couldn't get it to show up as multiple lines. And as a single line, it would not be correct Python code.

Answer (score 2):

Comprehensions allow you to have a short hand for creating various data types.
In this case you want to build generators.
This is as you don't need to build every number before reducing the list, to a single number.

Wrapping one in `sum` can allow you to significantly shorten `digit_sum`. Which can become:

```
def digit_sum(n):
    return sum(int(digit) for digit in str(n))
```

You can also change numerology to be a little shorter, if you combine the addition and assignment.

```
def numerology(word):
    total = 0
    for letter in word.upper():
        total = digit_sum(total + alphabets[letter])
    return total
```

If you want, you can use `functools.reduce` to make this span a total of six lines.

```
def numerology(word):
    return functools.reduce(
        lambda a, b: sum(int(digit) for digit in str(a + b)),
        (alphabets[letter] for letter in word.upper()),
        0
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner for laughs.

```
alphabets = {"A":1,"I":1,"J":1, "Q":1,"Y":1,"B":2,"K":2,"R":3,"C":3,"G":3,"L":3,"S":3,"D":4,"M":4,"T":4,"H":5,"E":5,"N":5,"X":5,"U":6,"V":6,"W":6,"O":7, "Z":7,"P":8,"F":8}
print("Your numerology score is "+ str((int(sum([alphabets[l] for l in input("Type your name:").upper() if l in alphabets.keys()])) % 9) or 9))
```

Answer (score 1):

this one !!!

```
a= input()
b= 0
c= len(a)
d= {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d":4, "e":5, "f":6, "g":7, "h":8, "i":9, "j":10, "k":11, "l":12, "m":13, "n":14, "o":15, "p":16, "q":17, "r":18, "s":19, "t":20, "u":21, "v":22, "w":23, "x":24, "y":25, "z":26, " ":0}
for i in range(c):
                    b= b+d[a[i]]
print(b)
```

[gematria](https://code.sololearn.com/c041Rr939U7b#py)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When providing an answer it helps to explain what your answer is doing so that the question asked can learn instead of just copying and pasting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

i'm sure you can chain the reducer functions a bit better but...

```
const charMap = {A:1, J:1, S:1, B:2, K:2, T:2, C:3, L:3, U:3, D:4, 
  M:4, V:4, E:5, N:5, W:5, F:6, O:6, X:6, G:7, P:7, Y:7, H:8, 
  Q:8, Z:8, I:9, R:9};

let name = prompt ("Type your name in CAPS"); //for example: TOM

let wordScore =  Array.from(name).reduce((nameScore, element) => {
    let curValue = charMap[element]
     return (nameScore + curValue)
  },0)

let finalScore = Array.from(String(wordScore), Number).reduce((score, element) => {

  return score > 10 ? score + element : score
})


alert(finalScore)
```